# Color swatch selector with multiple mouseover and mouseout functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a simple mouseout and mouseover functions. Basically, I have color boxes (or swatches) and I have to get the color of the specific box when hovered and when selected. You can see how it works in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b0o9xhr0/).

So I came out with a working script. But I am not sure how I can optimize or shorten the script since I will be having several color swatches. I made 2 samples swatches in this demo.

**The question:** is there a way to optimize/shorten it? Contents in the script were almost the same for each functions. The class names were the only ones changed.

```js
/* COLOR SWATCH 1*/

$(".color").mouseover(function() {
   var hex = $( this ).css("background-color");
   var hexVal = $( this ).attr("value");
   var styles = {
      backgroundColor : hex
    };
    $('.selected-color').css(styles);
    $('.selected-color').text(hexVal);
});

$(".color").mouseout(function() {
    var hex = $('.active').css( "background-color");
    var hexValue = $('.active').attr("value");
    var styles = {
      backgroundColor : hex
    };
    $('.selected-color').empty();
    $('.selected-color').css(styles);
    $('.selected-color').text(hexValue);
});


$('.color').on('click', function() {
   $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    var hex = $(this).css("background-color");
    var hexVal = $('.active').attr("value");
    var styles = {
      backgroundColor : hex
    };
    $('.selected-color').css(styles);
    $('.selected-color').text(hexVal);
}); 


/* COLOR SWATCH 2*/

$(".color-2").mouseover(function() {
   var hexs = $( this ).css("background-color");
   var hexVal = $( this ).attr("value");
   var styles = {
      backgroundColor : hexs
    };
    $('.selected-color-2').css(styles);
    $('.selected-color-2').text(hexVal);
});

$(".color-2").mouseout(function() {
    var hex = $('.active-2').css( "background-color");
    var hexValue = $('.active-2').attr("value");
    var styles = {
      backgroundColor : hex
    };
    $('.selected-color-2').empty();
    $('.selected-color-2').css(styles);
    $('.selected-color-2').text(hexValue);
});


$('.color-2').on('click', function() {
   $(this).addClass('active-2').siblings().removeClass('active-2');
    var hex = $(this).css("background-color");
    var hexVal = $('.active-2').attr("value");
    var styles = {
      backgroundColor : hex
    };
    $('.selected-color-2').css(styles);
    $('.selected-color-2').text(hexVal);
});
```

```css
.color-swatch div {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #313131;
    margin-right: 5px;
  }

.selected-color, .selected-color-2 {
    width: 90px;
    height: 20px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2px;

}  
.active, .active-2 {
    border: 3px solid #151515 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- COLOR SWATCH 1 -->
<p>SELECTED COLOR 1: <span class="selected-color" style="background-color:#ef4060;" value="Pink">Pink</span></p> 
<div class="color-swatch">
     <div class="color" style="background-color:#028482;" value="Aqua"></div>
     <div class="color" style="background-color:#4c0055;" value="Purple"></div>
     <div class="color active" style="background-color:#ef4060;" value="Pink"></div>         
</div>

<!-- COLOR SWATCH 2 -->
<br><br>
<p>SELECTED COLOR 2: <span class="selected-color-2" style="background-color:#028482;" value="Aqua">Aqua</span>
</p> 
<div class="color-swatch">
     <div class="color-2 active-2" style="background-color:#028482;" value="Aqua"></div>
     <div class="color-2" style="background-color:#4c0055;" value="Purple"></div>
     <div class="color-2" style="background-color:#ef4060;" value="Pink"></div>         
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### HTML abuse

The HTML5 specification does not allow a [`<div>` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/div.html) to have a `value` attribute.  You can use a [data-* attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) (named `data-color`, for example).  A [`title`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.title) attribute would also be reasonable.

You are misusing CSS classes as IDs.  An ID is a unique name for an individual element.  A class is a set of elements that should all be treated alike.  You should not have `color` and `color-2` as two class names.  Rather, they should be a single class.

### Confused terminology

Your wording is a bit off, in my opinion.  Each individual sample is a "swatch".  A color *selector* is a widget consisting of three *swatches*.

When you make a decision by clicking on a swatch, the swatch isn't just "active" — I would say that that color has been *selected*.

Based on the above, I would rename…

- the `color` and `color-2` classes both to `swatch`
- the `color-swatch` class to `swatch-selector`
- the `active` class to `selected`

### jQuery

Once you rename the classes so that both widgets have the same class names, it becomes possible to write code that treats the swatch selector as a generic widget.

If you need to define both a mouseover and a mouseout handler, use [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) instead.

```js
$(function() {
    'use strict';

    function showActiveColor($selector) {
        var selectorId = $selector.attr('id');
        var $selected = $selector.find('.swatch.selected');
        $('#active-' + selectorId).empty()
                                  .text($selected.data('color'))
                                  .css({ backgroundColor: $selected.css('background-color') });
    }

    $('.swatch-selector .swatch').hover(
        function mouseOver(event) {
            var colorName = $(this).data('color');
            var color = $(this).css('background-color');
            var selectorId = $(this).closest('.swatch-selector').attr('id');
            $('#active-' + selectorId).text(colorName)
                                      .css({ backgroundColor: color });
        },
        function mouseOut(event) {
            showActiveColor($(this).closest('.swatch-selector'));
        }
    ).click(function onClick(event) {
        $(this).addClass('selected')
               .siblings().removeClass('selected');
    });

    // Initialization so that you don't have to hard-code the span's
    // background-color and text to match the initial selection
    $('.swatch-selector').each(function(index, el) { showActiveColor($(el)); });
});
```

```css
.swatch-selector .swatch {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #313131;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.swatch-selector .swatch.selected {
    border: 3px solid #151515;
}
.color-name {
    width: 90px;
    height: 20px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- COLOR SWATCH SELECTOR 1 -->
<p>SELECTED COLOR 1: <span class="color-name" id="active-color-1"></span></p> 
<div class="swatch-selector" id="color-1">
     <div class="swatch" style="background-color:#028482;" data-color="Aqua"></div>
     <div class="swatch" style="background-color:#4c0055;" data-color="Purple"></div>
     <div class="swatch selected" style="background-color:#ef4060;" data-color="Pink"></div>         
</div>

<br><br>

<!-- COLOR SWATCH SELECTOR 2 -->
<p>SELECTED COLOR 2: <span class="color-name" id="active-color-2"></span></p> 
<div class="swatch-selector" id="color-2">
     <div class="swatch selected" style="background-color:#028482;" data-color="Aqua"></div>
     <div class="swatch" style="background-color:#4c0055;" data-color="Purple"></div>
     <div class="swatch" style="background-color:#ef4060;" data-color="Pink"></div>         
</div>
```

Comment: This is a very good answer, but wouldn't it be better to declare the variables outside the hover function to prevent re-creating them every time the event fires?

Answer (score 2):

I thought store the result of `$('.selected-color')` will be better since that DOM element is always there. Reduce jQuery selector will be good for performance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can just make a function that takes the class names as parameters like this:

```
function attachMouseEvents(elementClass, selectedColorClass, activeClass) {
    $(elementClass).mouseover(function() {
       var hex = $( this ).css("background-color");
       var hexVal = $( this ).attr("value");
       var styles = {
          backgroundColor : hex
        };
        $(selectedColorClass).css(styles);
        $(selectedColorClass).text(hexVal);
    });

    // apply same principle for mouseover and mouseout ...
}

attachMouseEvents('.color', '.selected-color', '.active');
attachMouseEvents('.color-2', '.selected-color-2', '.active-2');
```

Comment: Hi @lex82. Thank you, it worked when I added the mouseout event with the same layout. But it didn't run properly on my .click function. Did I miss out something? Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b0o9xhr0/3/

Comment: You forgot to replace two occurrences of '.selected-color-2' with selectedColorClass.

Answer (score 1):

By containing the individual colour selection blocks in a parent element with an appropriate class name, you can write you functions to find the correct siblings:

```
<!-- COLOR SWATCH 1 -->
<div class="swatch-holder">
    <p>SELECTED COLOR 1: <span class="selected-color" style="background-color:#ef4060;" value="Pink">Pink</span></p> 
  <div class="color-swatch">
     <div class="color" style="background-color:#028482;" value="Aqua"></div>
     <div class="color" style="background-color:#4c0055;" value="Purple"></div>
     <div class="color active" style="background-color:#ef4060;" value="Pink"></div>         
  </div>
</div>

<!-- COLOR SWATCH 2 -->
<div class="swatch-holder">

  <p>SELECTED COLOR 2: <span class="selected-color" style="background-color:#028482;" value="Aqua">Aqua</span>
  </p> 
  <div class="color-swatch">
     <div class="color active" style="background-color:#028482;" value="Aqua"></div>
     <div class="color" style="background-color:#4c0055;" value="Purple"></div>
     <div class="color" style="background-color:#ef4060;" value="Pink"></div>         
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".color").mouseover(function() {
    var holder = $(this).parents('.swatch-holder');
    var selectedColor = holder.find('span.selected-color');
    var hex = $( this ).css("background-color");
    var hexVal = $( this ).attr("value");
    var styles = {
        backgroundColor : hex
    };
    //jquery methods are chainable:  
    selectedColor.css(styles).text(hexVal);

});

$(".color").mouseout(function() {
    var holder = $(this).parents('.swatch-holder');
    var selectedColor = holder.find('span.selected-color');
    var hex = holder.find('.active').css( "background-color");
    var hexVal = holder.find('.active').attr("value");
    var styles = {
      backgroundColor : hex
    };  
    selectedColor.css(styles).text(hexVal);
});


$('.color').on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    var holder = $(this).parents('.swatch-holder');
    var selectedColor = holder.find('span.selected-color');
    var hex = $(this).css("background-color");
    var hexVal = $(this).attr("value");
    var styles = {
      backgroundColor : hex
    };  
    selectedColor.css(styles).text(hexVal);
});
```

Note there is still an amount of duplication in the 3 functions themselves, and as pointed out in another answer, you should use `data-` attributes rather than `value` on your `div.color` elements, but this is a start.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mwx2pr6k/1/

Note i also edited the css a little